# How to automaticly register components using a Generic FactoryMethod with Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I´m trying to work out a problem with registering my configuration classes. I have the following in my Installer:

First I register my open generic factory

```
        container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For(typeof (IConfigurationProvider<>))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof (AppSettingsConfigurationProvider<>)));
```

Then I´m trying to register all concrete impl. of IConfiguration and I need to use my registered impl. IConfigurationProvider to resolve them.

Problem is that my factory looks like this:

```
public class AppSettingsConfigurationProvider<TConfiguration>
    where TConfiguration : class, IConfiguration, new()
{
    public TConfiguration Build()
    {
        var config = new TConfiguration();

        var properties = typeof(TConfiguration).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (!p.CanWrite) 
                continue;

            if (p.GetSetMethod(false) == null) 
                continue;

            var settingsKey = string.Format("{0}.{1}", p.ReflectedType.FullName, p.Name);

            p.SetValue(config, Convert.ChangeType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingsKey], p.PropertyType), null);
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

So I need to set the generic type.

Is there a way to get away with this, so that I dont need to register each configuration component one by one like this:

```
        container
            .Register(
                Component.For<DummyConfiguration>()
                    .ImplementedBy<DummyConfiguration>()
                        .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider<DummyConfiguration>>().Build()));
```

I would prefer a more automatic way to register my configuration componets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something similar to what [Ben Hall described](http://codebetter.com/benhall/2010/07/22/improving-testability-with-the-castle-dictionary-adapter/), using DictionaryAdapter work for you? Notice that if you're using Windsor 2.5 you already have DictionaryAdapter (it is part of `Castle.Core.dll` now).

Comment: Yes, It does solve the problem, thank you Krysztof! But, Lets say I would like to load my configuration from some other store, a database for example. Is there a way to register all configuration components implementing IConfiguration and then have Windsor automaticly infer the type for the registered IConfigurationProvider<> component?